# Show categorical x-axis values when making line plot from pandas Series in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I get the x-axis values of [a, b, c] to show up?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get your xtick labels to show using `plt.xticks`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s.plot()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(s.index)), s.index)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are a lifesaver sir!  I never would have figured that out!