# How to draw line graph in python by using groupby on one column and count of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

Dataset

```
Age    factor1    factor2
20-25    0           1
26-30    0           0
31-35    1           0
20-25    1           1
26-30    0           1
20-25    1           0
```

I want to a line graph in python and groupby the value 'Age' (x-axis) and y-axis is the count of the number of times '1' comes in the factor1 column.

I tried the code below but it shows the count of number of times the 'age' category repeats instead of the count of 1 in factor1

```
df.groupby('Age')['factor1'].count().plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Age,df.factor1)
factor1  0  1
Age          
20-25    1  2
26-30    2  0
31-35    0  1

pd.crosstab(df.Age,df.factor1)[1].plot(kind='line')
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get names on the x-axis from the Age column? When I change the kind of graph to bar it shows but not in line

Comment: @Ajinkya check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot,

Comment: I checked that, it only sets one label for the x-axis as it shows in the above image i.e Age. But I want to print the values in Age there like 20-25, 26-30 and 31-35

Comment: @Ajinkya how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961169/show-categorical-x-axis-values-when-making-line-plot-from-pandas-series-in-matpl

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem.